# Solve limit of integral through taylor

Tags: integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

> Show using Taylor expansion that $$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac4{\pi r^2} \int_0^{2\pi} f(a+r\cos \theta , b +r\sin \theta)\cos{2\theta}d\theta = f_{xx} (a,b) - f_{yy}(a,b)$$
>   where $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is $C^3.$

Why is Taylor expansion helpful? [There's a lot of terms when doing it three times.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Example_in_two_dimensions) Why is $C^3$ helpful? Does the $r\cos\theta$ indicate I should be converting to rectangular? How would that help?

Answer (score 1):

Since $f\in C^3$, [the Taylor expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $f(x,y)$ at $x=a,y=b$ is
$$ f(x,y)=f(a,b)+f_x(a,b)(x-a)+f_y(a,b)(y-b)+\frac12f_{xx}(a,b)(x-a)^2+f_{xy}(a,b)(x-a)(y-b)+\frac12f_{yy}(a,b)(y-b)^2+r_3(x,y)$$
where $r_3(x,y)=O((|x-a|+|y-b|)^3)$. I hope this answers your question since
$$ \lim_{r\to0}\frac{1}{\pi r^2}\int_0^{2\pi}r_3(x,y)\cos2\theta d\theta=0.$$

Comment: I'm still confused where I'm supposed to be going with this. What happens to all the other terms that I end up with just the double derivatives?

Comment: @Feli, it is just direct computation for other terms. For example, $\int_0^{2\pi}f_x(a,b)r\cos(2\theta)d\theta=0$ and $\int_0^{2\pi}f_{xx}(a,b)r^2\cos^2\theta\cos(2\theta)d\theta=\frac{\pi r^2}{2}f_{xx}(a,b)$.