# Solving limit of Integral through Taylor

Tags: integration, limits, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

> Let $u:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ($U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$) be twice continously differentiable. Evaluate the limit:
>   $$\lim_{r\to 0^+} \frac1{r^2} \Bigg( \frac1{4\pi} \iint\limits_{\xi^2+\eta^2+\zeta^2=1} u(x+r\xi,y+r\eta,z+r\zeta) \enspace dS(\xi,\eta,\zeta) - u(x,y,z) \Bigg)$$
>   Tip: use the Taylors theorem

I parametrised $\xi,\eta,\zeta$ to spherical $\theta,\phi,R$. Since $R=1$ everywhere it's dropped. Leaving the integral as

$$\int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi} \int_{\phi = 0}^{2\pi} u(x+r\sin\theta\cos\phi,y+r\sin\theta\sin\phi,z+r\cos\theta)\,\sin\theta \enspace d\phi\, d\theta$$

I then tried a Taylor Expansion of $u(x,y,z)$ at $u(x+r\sin\theta\cos\phi,y+r\sin\theta\sin\phi,z+r\cos\theta)$ which would look like

$$u(x,y,z)=u(...)-u_x(r\sin\theta\cos\phi)-u_y(r\sin\theta\sin\phi)-u_z(r\cos\theta)+ \frac12 \Big(u_{xx}\,r^2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi + u_{yy}\,r^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi + u_{zz}\,r^2\cos^2\theta + \\
2u_{xy}\,r^2\sin^2\theta\cos\phi\sin\phi + 2u_{xz}\,r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\cos\phi + 2u_{yz}\,r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\sin\phi\Big)$$
but I'm not sure what do now. Since i only know about my functions parameteters i can't say that there isn't a $\theta$ or $\phi$ in my partial Derivatives, or is that wrong?

This problem is very related to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217386/solve-limit-of-integral-through-taylor), but I didn't quite understand how he managed the Integral and where all the polar coordiantes went.

Comment: Tip: First assume that $x = y = z = 0$, that simplifies writing. Then do the Taylor expansion _before_ introducing spherical coordinates. $$u(r\xi, r\eta, r\zeta) = u(0) + u_x(0)r\xi + u_y(0)r\eta + u_z(0)r\zeta + \frac{1}{2}u_{xx}(0)r^2\xi^2 + \frac{1}{2} u_{yy}(0)r^2\eta^2 + \frac{1}{2} u_{zz}(0) r^2\zeta^2 + u_{xy}(0)r^2\xi\eta + u_{yz}(0)r^2\eta\zeta + u_{zx}(0)r^2\xi\zeta + o(r^2).$$ Well, you don't even need to introduce spherical coordinates. Symmetry suffices.

Comment: @Daniel-Fischer ah that expansion makes more sense, can i just integrate those and treat the partial derivatives as constants?

Comment: They _are_ constants, so they may as well be treated as constants.

Comment: @DanielFischer ah right, my bad. Thank you